# How to combine the current line and the next line based on a pattern that exists in the next line. (Using awk)

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, awk

I have tried countless recommendations in this site for the awk syntax but somehow i cannot get my head around awk..

I am trying to combine two lines ( the current one and the next one ) only when my expr exists in the next line.

For example I have a text file which contains the following:

```
<option value="1" selected> channel 1 
<div id="program_13" class="tree_3"><input type="checkbox" name="output_checkbox" value="13">&nbsp; &nbsp;Somename1</div>
<option value="2" selected> channel 2 
<div id="program_21" class="tree_3"><input type="checkbox" name="output_checkbox" value="21">&nbsp; &nbsp;Someothername</div>
<option value="3" selected> channel 3 
<option value="4" selected> channel 4 
<option value="5" selected> channel 5
```

I want to join the current line with the next one only when the "output_checkbox" expression exists within the next line. This may be truth for all OR any of the 5 main lines.

On the example above, my desired result would be :

```
<option value="1" selected> channel 1 <div id="program_13" class="tree_3"><input type="checkbox" name="output_checkbox" value="13">&nbsp; &nbsp;Somename1</div>
<option value="2" selected> channel 2 <div id="program_21" class="tree_3"><input type="checkbox" name="output_checkbox" value="21">&nbsp; &nbsp;Someothername</div>
<option value="3" selected> channel 3 
<option value="4" selected> channel 4 
<option value="5" selected> channel 5
```

I am hoping to get the following at the end by using sed (which i think i can handle):

```
channel 1: Somename1
channel 2: Someothername
channel 3: 
channel 4: 
channel 5:
```

I am looking forward to your suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this line:

```
awk '/output_checkbox/{printf "%s",$0;next}{printf (NR>1?"\n%s":"%s"), $0}END{print ""}' file
```

little test:

```
kent$  cat f
<option value="1" selected> channel 1 
<div id="program_13" class="tree_3"><input type="checkbox" name="output_checkbox" value="13">&nbsp; &nbsp;Somename1</div>
<option value="2" selected> channel 2 
<div id="program_21" class="tree_3"><input type="checkbox" name="output_checkbox" value="21">&nbsp; &nbsp;Someothername</div>
<option value="3" selected> channel 3 
<option value="4" selected> channel 4 
<option value="5" selected> channel 5

kent$  awk '/output_checkbox/{printf "%s",$0;next}{printf (NR>1?"\n%s":"%s"), $0}END{print ""}' f 
<option value="1" selected> channel 1 <div id="program_13" class="tree_3"><input type="checkbox" name="output_checkbox" value="13">&nbsp; &nbsp;Somename1</div>
<option value="2" selected> channel 2 <div id="program_21" class="tree_3"><input type="checkbox" name="output_checkbox" value="21">&nbsp; &nbsp;Someothername</div>
<option value="3" selected> channel 3 
<option value="4" selected> channel 4 
<option value="5" selected> channel 5
```

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following:

```
/output_checkbox/ { sub(/\n/, "", last); printf "%s" last; print; last = "" }

!/output_checkbox/ { printf "%s" last; last = ($0  "\n"); } 

END { printf "%s" last }
```

Comment: never use printf with input data as the format argument or you'll get nasty surprises when your input contains formatting characters (e.g. `%s`). Use `printf "%s" last`, not `printf last`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just keep the previous line in a variable:

```
awk '/pattern/{print prev $0;prev="";next} prev{print prev} {prev=$0} END{print prev}'
```

As @Kent points out, there is an ambiguity in the problem specification: What is desired if two consecutive lines match `/pattern/` (I gather this is not an issue in the actual problem presented in the OP.)

My little program assumes that the intent is that `/pattern/` be appended to the previous line only if the previous line did not itself match `/pattern/`. So it will turn:

```
<line>1
<pattern>2
<pattern>3
```

into

```
<line>1<pattern>2
<pattern>3
```

But there is another interpretation, where all `/pattern/` lines are appended, producing:

```
<line>1<pattern>2<pattern>3
```

To get that result, a simple modification:

```
awk '/pattern/{prev = prev $0; next} prev{print prev} {prev=$0} END{print prev}'
```

NOTE: Both of those programs delete blank lines.

Comment: could have problem if there are continuous `/patter/` lines

Comment: @Kent: I guess that depends on what is desired in that case. In the above, I explicitly reset `prev` to avoid repetition, but the alternative would be to replace the first execution block with `{prev=prev $0; next}`

Comment: the command in your UPDATE won't give that result. it overwritten the `prev` in `{prev=$0}`. you need to find the right point to output. anyway, your first one-liner may already solve OP's problem....

Comment: @kent: oops. Let me fix that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue about Awk but if you would like to have a normal pattern, this one would work:

```
.+?(channel .+?)(?:(?:\s|\z)+?.+? &nbsp;(.+?)</div>)?
```

the result would be that:

```
channel 1 Somename1
channel 2 Someothername
channel 3   
channel 4   
channel 5
```

If you want to use awk, this could help you:
http://www.unixcl.com/search/label/Awk

Comment: This doesn't check for the condition if "output_checkbox" expression exists

Comment: There is no need for this. Look at his post what he wants as the end result. Its Exept from the : exactly the same!